# Create custom tag for web layout like Joomla or Blogger

Tags: php, templates

Joomla template have custom tag like:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" >`

or blogger

`<b:include data='blog' name=''/>`
(im not sure whether It is the same thing)

I need to know how to create something like that for templating. I google it for hours, but can't find such thing, may be I have no right keywords. I doubt if it just make use of string replacement. is that xml? xhtml? what is that and how to get started with it with PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Custom Tags allows you to be implement this quite easily. https://github.com/buggedcom/PHP-Custom-Tags